# Laravel 5.4 Getting issue in fetching from databse in Json

Tags: laravel-5

I have been fetching data from database and in return json I got this format. 
As you see, I need to remove extra brackets and "0".

This is the code:

```
$showid=User::create($request->all());
return str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode(['statusCode'=>'0','statusMessage'=>'Success',$showid]), ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

Return output:

```
{
    "0": {
        "Email": "fghgfkfakgf@gmail.com",
        "Password": "hahah",
        "Role": "2",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-19 10:59:54",
        "created_at": "2017-04-19 10:59:54",
        "id": 135
    },
    "statusCode": "0",
    "statusMessage": "Success"
}
```

And I want to output like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": "0",
    "statusMessage": "Success",
    "Email": "fghgfkfakgf@gmail.com",
    "Password": "hahah",
    "Role": "2",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-19 10:59:54",
    "created_at": "2017-04-19 10:59:54",
    "id": 135
}
```

Check the following image.

[Jason Return Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhkGn.png)

Comment: please add the json

Comment: {
  "0": {
    "Email": "fghgfkfakgf@gmail.com",
    "Password": "hahah",
    "Role": "2",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-19 10:59:54",
    "created_at": "2017-04-19 10:59:54",
    "id": 135
  },
  "statusCode": "0",
  "statusMessage": "Success"
}

Comment: am using this code to display json  

$showid=User::create($request->all());
         //$Role = DB::table('users')->where('Email', $Email)->value('Role');
         //return response()->json(['statusCode'=>'0','statusMessage'=>'Success',$showid],400);
              return str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode(['statusCode'=>'0','statusMessage'=>'Success',$showid]), ENT_NOQUOTES));

Comment: please check code again. i edit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$showid=User::create($request->all()); 
$rs = [
        'statusCode' => '0',
        'statusMessage' => 'Success'
    ];

return response()->json(array_merge($rs, $showid));
```

Answer (score 0):

echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode(['statusCode'=>'0','statusMessage'=>'Success',$showid]), ENT_NOQUOTES));

Answer (score 0):

return str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode(array(['statusCode'=>'0','statusMessage'=>'Success',$showid]), ENT_NOQUOTES)));